# TYPO3 how get parent category of a sub category

Tags: typo3, categories, extbase, tx-news

I have TYPO3 (7.6.10) and tx_news (News Administration)
I created a page with list of news.
I need to know the parent category of a sub-category (because I need to style the header of a page).

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

- `GeorgRinger\News\Domain\Model\Category` (tx_news) has a property `parentcategory`
- `TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\Category` (core) has a property `parent`

If you want to display the title of a parent category in a news template using fluid, you could do the following:

```
<f:if condition="{newsItem.firstCategory.parentcategory}">
  <f:then>{newsItem.firstCategory.parentcategory.title}</f:then>
  <f:else>{newsItem.firstCategory.title}</f:else>
</f:if>
```

Comment: there is a way to get the variable overwriteDemand and pass it to the page and then get the parent category? (maybe with tsconfig)

Comment: Are you in a front-end or back-end context (because TSconfig is basically back-end)? Is the category that you want to resolve bound to a news entity or to a page - if it's a page, which one, the one containing the plugin rendering the news entities or the one storing the news if using a storage folder?

Comment: The context is: Front End.
It's a page.
I want the parent category of the category passed via url by plugin, i think is: [overwriteDemand][categories]=x
The page contain the plugin that renders the news entities.